# PostgreSQL: Don't fire statement trigger if only one specific column updated

Tags: postgresql

I have a statement trigger on a person table in PostgreSQL that refreshes a materialized view whenever the person table is updated. One of the columns is a bytea to store an image uploaded from PHP. This column is not in the materialized view. There is a row trigger on the person table to update the image upload date column whenever the image column is updated. How can I prevent the statement trigger from firing if the row trigger fires?

```
create or replace function person_photo_date_func() returns trigger as $$
    begin
        new.photo_utc := current_timestamp;
        return new;
    end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger person_photo_date_tg
    after update of photo on person
    for each row execute procedure person_photo_date_func();

create or replace function refresh_mv() returns trigger as $$
    begin
        refresh materialized view vm_csr;
        return null;
    end
$$ language plpgsql security definer;

create trigger refresh_mat_views_person
    after insert or update or delete or truncate
    on person for each statement
    execute procedure refresh_mv();
```

Comment: Dont understand your flow or your problem.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the problem is very specific, but it's asked correctly. I do get his problem.

Comment: @Andy I've tried to provide a solution, but as you see it's getting complicated. I would move the calling of refresh materialized view to app logic instead of DB logic, if it's possible. Also, is it possible that user updates some person data that is present in mat view and photo at the same statement, i.e. UPDATE person SET photo = '...', location = '... ' ? If so then your logic will do skip the refresh of mat view. If you have only one application doing updates on DB, I would move calling of mat view refresh to application logic, when you have better seing of what's updated and when.

Comment: @StanBrajewski Just because you think understand the question doesnt mean OP shouldnt write a better description of the problem.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza So what's not readable in OPs question for you? Instead of general 'Write it again' it would be better to  say what's not readable, so the OP could precise the situation for You

Comment: @StanBrajewski I dont waste my time trying to understand bad written question. If OP doesnt take the time why should I? I provide the link with recomendation on how write better question. Is up to him take it or not. Is also up to you try to answer it, but my experience is if quesion isnt clear you end answering the wrong question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this, someone has tried the same, to disable thr trigger from the stored procedure https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48402/disabling-triggers-in-stored-procedures

I would redesign this. You could use some 'status' table in which your  person_photo_date_func() will put 'transactions' to be skipped by refresh_mv().

```
create table skip_refresh_mv (id serial primary key, xid integer);

create or replace function person_photo_date_func() returns trigger as $$
    begin
        new.photo_utc := current_timestamp;
        INSERT INTO skip_refresh_mv (xid) SELECT txid_current();
        return new;
    end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create or replace function refresh_mv() returns trigger as $$
    begin
      IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM skip_refresh_mv WHERE xid = txid_current()) THEN
        refresh materialized view vm_csr;
      END IF;        
      return null;
    end
$$ language plpgsql security definer;
```

But it's assuming one statement per transaction

You also need to clean-up old records from the skip_refresh_mv, so add some timestamp column to skip_refresh_mv table and do routine cleanup of old records.

If you have at-most one such statement per transaction then you could also cleanup the records from inside `refresh_mv()` , after checking for existence.

P.S. I you need to do it per statement I would use pg_stat_activity.
You can get current transaction active query with this:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity where state = 'active' and backend_xid = txid_current()::integer;
```

Comment: The documentation does say that the triggers are fired in name order (alphabetical?) but does not say that it distinguishes between row and statement triggers in the firing order. Can I assume that the triggers will fire in the correct order as currently named?

Comment: @Andy There's is info about that in docs, found here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/trigger-definition.html look for this text: in this paragraph: "Statement-level BEFORE triggers naturally fire before the statement starts to do anything, while statement-level AFTER triggers fire at the very end of the statement. ... Row-level BEFORE triggers fire immediately before a particular row is operated on, while row-level AFTER triggers fire at the end of the statement (but before any statement-level AFTER triggers). ...."

Comment: I didn't catch the trigger order the first time. I was probably going too fast. Thanks for the info, it seems straight forward now. I have an aversion to database consistancy logic in the app. I don't have any guarantee that SQL won't be used, so I prefer database logic where I can. And especially since the app isn't done yet I need to make sure the database stays clean. Since PostgreSQL doesn't have packages like Oracle the stray table sounds like the next best way to pass a hint from one trigger to another. From reading elsewhere it sounds like I'll need a table anyway to log refreshes.

Comment: It's all in place and seems to be working as designed, except that new.photo_utc is NOT being updated with the current timestamp. What would cause this to not work?

Comment: @Andy, you have AFTER UPDATE trigger so setting NEW.photo_utc and returning NEW does not update the record. You should use BEFORE trigger for that.

Comment: @Andy Is the solution ok? Are you going to accept the answer?

Comment: It's close enough. I ditched the serial and used xid as the primary key and added a timestamp column so I could track refreshes.